# Discord.js check role existence

Tags: javascript, discord.js, message, member

So as I said in my last stackoverflow question about discord.js they recently updated and I want to know how to check if a member have a role. You must know that `message.guild.member(message.author).roles.has("688366821895700480")` won't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Discord.js v11.x it's:
`message.member.roles.has()`

On v12.x it's 
`message.member.roles.cache.has()`

Be aware that this will only work if the message does come from a guild.  Test message.member for undefined if it is unknown.

You can do it the way you were attempting by going through the guild object, but it's more complex than it needs to be compared to using the above method.